# using phrase "weekend of"

Tags: idioms, time, dates

Say the 24th is a Monday and you say that you’ll be doing something the weekend of the 24th, meaning the 22nd and 23rd. Isn’t that incorrect? I would say the weekend of the 24th means the 29th and 30th.

Comment: For **me** - this is entirely idiolectal - the weekend is not the end of the week. There would be no 'weekend of the 24th' (the 'end of the week of the 24th' is something entirely different, viz the 27th-28th). There's a 'weekend of the 22nd' and a week later a 'weekend of the 29th'.

Answer (score 7):

I'd argue that in the given month, the 'weekend of the 24<sup>th</sup>' is a misnomer; Monday is not normally a weekend day at all.  Friday evening (the 21<sup>st</sup> of the given month) might *just* be counted as part of the weekend.  And if it is a holiday weekend, then Monday might scrape as part of the long weekend, but normally, you would only reference a date that is part of the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not talk about the weekend of the 24th:

S_M_T_W_Th_F_S

16 17 18 19 20 21 22

23 24 25 26 27 28 29

30 31

I would say the weekend of the 22nd or 23rd.

Also the weekend of the 29th or 30th.

The week of the 24th has weekend days of the 23rd and 29th, those are the days that are on the ends of the week that contains the date of the 24th.

Answer (score 0):

Specificity is best practice. As a speaker and writer of English, I'd say and write "weekend of Saturday (or Sunday) the __" to be as specific as possible.

However, I'm also a person who hears and reads a good deal of English. I'd assume that "the weekend of Monday the __" means the one in 5-6 days, and so on with other days of the week, unless it's obvious otherwise. I consider it likely that you'll run into the ambiguous usages, so take care to be on the same page.

It's a contextual (and therefore ambiguous) expression if you give a date outside the weekend. Barring even different calendar schemes (Chinese, Arabic, and Jewish Lunar calendars, for example), it's poor, but common, practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of partially right answers. While we refer to the weekends as Saturday and Sunday. The truth is the weeks actually starts on Sunday and runs through Saturday. So technically part of a weekend starts at the beginning and another weekend starts at the end of the week. So when someone says, for example, the weekend of the 24th (the 24th being a Monday) they are not using good grammar or reference. The 24th doesn’t fall on a weekend day ... therefor there is NO “weekend of the 24th. Because you could be potentially talking about the weekend before OR after that date. The correct way to express this would be ... the weekend before the 24th, or the weekend after the 24th.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the weekend begins when you leave work Friday and ends when you return to work Monday. When you say to a co-worker "have a nice weekend," you don't intend for that sentiment to begin the next day, rather you're referring to that time forward until they return to work Monday when you see them again.

So, I reference Friday along with the date when I say "the weekend of" or "the weekend starting." And even if you don't work with someone and happen to see them Friday, you would say the same thing, and if you saw them Saturday, you would say "have a nice rest of your weekend."

Answer (score -1):

A week begins on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. 
That is why Sat and Sun are collectively known as the "weekEND".

So, for a week beginning on the 24th of a month:

(1) 24th would be a Monday. The 29th and the 30th would be the "weekend".

(2) The dates from 24 through 30 comprise the "week of the 24th". Note though that one could ALSO say "week of the 25th" or "week of the 30th" to refer to this week as long as the date used falls between 24 and 30.

(3) The dates 29 and 30 could be referred to weekend of the 29th or weekend of the 30th.